# Why is this makeblastdb command not working?

Tags: fasta, blast

I am trying to make local databases for the ncbi-blast+ package (version 2.60). I am doing so for 4 T-cell receptor genes. 3 of the 4 (TRAV, TRAJ, TRBV) have worked fine, but I am having problems with TRBJ. I say this because they should be the same format and if one works the rest works.

They take the format below:

```
>K02545|TRBJ1-1*01|Homo sapiens|F|J-REGION|749..796|48 nt|3| | | |15 AA|15+0=15| | |
NTEAFFGQGTRLTVV
```

I used the following command (like I say, it was fine for the rest, oddly enough):

```
makeblastdb -in TRBJ_AA.fa -parse_seqids -dbtype prot
```

and I get the following error message:

```
BLAST options error: TRBJ_AA.fa does not match input format type, default input type is FASTA
```

One issue I checked was the length of the sequences being too short, but I believe 11 is the minimum length required (for inputs, don't know if that is the same for databases)- but would someone be able to confirm, that strikes me as the most likely candidate?

I'm happy to use some other metric, but I was hoping on keeping BLAST for consistency's sake for the time being.

Thank you.

edit: I know it's to late, but for reference I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS x86_64 for all steps.

Comment: What operating system are you running this on and what operating system was the input file created on? Also, please [edit] your question and show us the actual file you are using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `makeblastdb`. Removing the final `| | |` from your sequence's description makes it work:

```
>K02545|TRBJ1-1*01|Homo sapiens|F|J-REGION|749..796|48 nt|3| | | |15 AA|15+0=15
```

So does removing everything after the 1st space:

```
>K02545|TRBJ1-1*01|Homo sapiens|F|J-REGION|749..796|48
```

There is nothing in the FASTA definition that would explain this and, even more weirdly, the presence of the `| | |` alone isn't enough to trigger the issue. I played around with this a little and it looks like it doesn't like the combination of `+` or `-`along with empty `| |`, but there's no clear pattern I can see:

These fail:

```
>| | |15-| | |
>| | |15+| | |
>| | |15-1| | |
>| | |15+1| | |
```

These work:

```
>| |15+| |
>| | |151| | |
```

So yeah, sounds like a bug. I suggest you report it to the NCBI devs. In the meantime, a simple fix would be to just keep the first space-separated field of your fasta header. Pass your fasta file through this:

```
awk '{print $1}' fasta.fa > new.fa
```

That will print the 1st field of each line and, assuming you don't have spaces in your sequence, it should effectively sort this out for you.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is a bug per se -- FASTA headers can use any combination of [these specific identifiers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21097/table/A632/?report=objectonly). It's parsing it somehow (assuming it's figuring out which of the possible identifiers to use based the parsing the + and - as strings), but it must be getting confused by the addition of three empty columns.

Comment: @OrdiNeu what it is after > is left for the user to decide if NCBI decides to add these identifiers or more is their own decision but it should be able to work with other identifiers

Comment: @OrdiNeu the FASTA format itself allows anything you care to put there. The identifiers you linked to are just what NCBI tends to use in *its* FASTA files, but they have nothing to do with the FASTA format. If a program expects a specific format, then the program is buggy. The fact that there's no clear pattern and that the issue occurs both with and without the `-parse_seqids` flag is further indication of a bug.

Comment: Oddly I found on my system that whether or not it 'works' also depends on the sequence lines. For example, take header `>| | |151| | |` and sequence `ATGAAGAG` it fails, with `ATGAAGAG\nATG` it works (in both cases running `makeblastdb  -dbtype nucl -in my_fasta.fa`)

Comment: @Chris_Rands curiouser and curiouser. But that makes it even more likely that this is a bug.

Comment: @terdon Yes, can you replicate what I described?

Comment: @terdon That's ahem... interesting! The 3 empty columns can be found in the other IMGT sequence headers, which were parsed successfuly- whereas the numerics with +/- are only found in the problem file which does place the blame firmly at their door. It also still doesn't work when leaving out the -parseseq_id flag. Will report it. Thanks for maintaining my sanity.

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes and no. The one you say works, kinda works on my system but complains about `BLAST Database creation error: Defline lacks a proper ID around line 1`. Changing the defline to `>a| | |151| | |`, however, reproduces what you describe perfectly: sequence `ATGAAGAG` fails but sequence `ATGAAGAG\nATG` works. Weird.

Comment: @TW93 you're welcome. I know how you feel. I'd have wondered about my own sanity too had I encountered this in the wild.